# Is $t^4 + 7$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

There aren't any linear factors, $-7$ doesn't have a square root in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ so I've ruled out those 'easy' factorisations. I'm not sure how to continue. Looking for a hint, not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended hints:

1. Calculate the order of $-7$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{17}^*$. In what follows I call it $n$.
2. Because $n$ is a power of two (how did I know that in advance?) you can deduce that any zero $\alpha$ of $x^4+7$ has order $4n$ ($\alpha$ is in some finite extension field $\Bbb{F}_{17^k}$).
3. Recall that the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_{17^k}^*$ is cyclic of order $17^k-1$. Use this to determine $k$.
4. What's the connection between $k$ and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$?

Comment: (1) $n = 16$; (2) $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^*$ is a 2-group; (3) $k = 4$ and (4) $k$ is the degree of $\alpha$'s minimal polynomial. So it's irreducible. This was super helpful and elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Correct. Good job, @Stanley! Hopefully the hints were at a suitable level of detail.

Comment: Yes, they were :)